# How do I create a onMouseOver tag in pyGTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, widget, glade

How do I create a onMouseOver tag?

For example when you put the mouse over the BACK button of Firefox, it shows up a little yellow box with the explanation of the button's function.

Is it a widget ?  Whats the correct name of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's called tooltips

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktooltip.html

On a `gtk.Widget` you can call the method `set_tooltip_text` or `set_tooltip_markup` to produce the desired effect

http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--set-tooltip-text